# Create Custom Tool with ArcObjects SDK and Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: visual-studio, arcobjects

I'm researching building a couple of custom tools.  I downloaded and installed ArcObjects SDK 10.4 to integrate it into Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, but I'm having trouble finding any good examples on creating the tools.  Our client wants one tool that will search for a value from a specific field("Loc_Num") within a specific set of layers and then highlight the feature it finds.  They also want another one to do an address lookup, but apparently the built-in tool is not what they are wanting.

Can anyone could point me to a good reference on building these within VS 2013 or 2015?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is in the [ArcObjects Help for .Net Developer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_Help_for_NET_developers/0001000002zs000000/), more specifically [Building Add-ins for ArcGIS Desktop](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/)

Comment: Good links here. Just to add, it doesnt sound like you need a full gp (geoprocessing tool). Dont get confused trying to build a "gp tool". An addin as suggested should do what you need.

Comment: I tried following a tutorial I found here:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n5000000

It uses Visual Studio 2008 so it doesn't follow along exactly.  Also when I insert the code snippet using VS2015 I get errors that Geometry, Carto or Display aren't under ESRI.ArcGIS.  I installed ArcObjects SDK for the Microsoft .NET Framework.  Do I need to install something else.  The tutorial isn't necessarily related to what I need a tool to do, I'm just trying to see if I can first create one, build and deploy for use in a custom toolbar.

Comment: You can also build a gp tool and call / execute / set parameters within the add-in but the path to the tool needs to be hard coded in the addin or you need place the gp tool in a known location. In any case, the tool needs to exist and the addin needs to be able to reference it in that location. Such addins should be distributed along with the gp tools and installation instructions.

Comment: @bdk0172 - that's the starting point. When i was migrating my tools from VBA to VB.Net and the SDK that's the tutorial i used.

Comment: @bdk0172 - this may be a .Net debugging question. Do all the neccessady libraries appear in your project references? ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto is installed in by default  "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.3\DotNet\ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.dll" for example

Comment: Yes, the dll's were all there.  I referenced them in the project and now everything's good.  Apparently the ArcGIS template didn't do everything for me as I was lead to believe from the tutorial.  Thanks for your help so far.  I may need to bug you as I go about creating the "Find" and "Address Lookup" tools.

Comment: @bdk0172 - the tutorials are not perfect, true. However when you create a tool using the SDK, the core references for the basic functionality should be added. If you want additional functionality from another library, this must be added and referenced in addition to those already referenced.

Comment: I was able to get the tutorial working so I could use it within ArcMap 10.4, but we just found out from our client that the tools need to work within an old VB6 built app.  I attempted to add it to the app using "Add From File..." and got "An error occurred when trying to add commands.".  I'm assuming I need to build the tools using ArcObjects SDK 9.3 and probably within VB6 as well.  Is it even possible to download 9.3 anymore?

Comment: @bdk0172 - i don't think there was SDK for 9.3. if so it wasn't as comprehensive as it is now.  The process of building and implementing tools was completaly updated in 10.0.  Tools and addins you delevelop will only work in newer versions but not in older versions of ArcGIS.  It's been a while but I believe you can build dll tools with arcobjects from scratch then register the dll and add as a custom tool.  You can however also develop tools in VBA templates directly in version 9. Unlike in v. 10, altering the template will make the tool available globaly. (in version 10 VBA it's only local)

Comment: I'm following another tutorial here:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Custom_selection_extension/0001000003w2000000/

This uses ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns which it appears you need to use if you want comboboxes, buttons, etc. on your add-in.  I compiled the tool and am trying to register it on a machine that only has the ArcGIS engine runtime on it.  When using ESRIRegASM it complains that the desktop.addins can't be found.  This is the setup that most of our customers will have.  How can I work around this?